# Images Symfony CMF create.js

Tags: createjs, symfony-cmf, hallo-js

I have installed Symfony CMF and everything works fine, but not like in cmf.liip.ch 
In cmf.liip.ch when I try to add image it can be uploaded, but in my application createjs does not allow me with this option ? 
So everything is by default in my application and still it does not works. 
Could anyone provide me with an answer or it would be better if someone provide me with kind of documentation ?? Thanks

Comment: Image upload does have some problems atm. We hope to solve this, either fixing the issues or switching the default editor to ckeditor, see https://github.com/symfony-cmf/CreateBundle/issues/59

Comment: OK, at least I know that everybody are having this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We are currently moving from hallo.js to ckeditor as the default wysiwig editor. it will hopefully soon be completed: https://github.com/symfony-cmf/cmf-sandbox/pull/199